# Insert grid and draw co-ordinates in the map layout in QGIS

Tags: qgis

In map [image], I need to insert a grid and draw co-ordinates. The projection of the layer in the map is EPSG-32644. The extension of the map is roughly 30° 33'0-30° 34'N / 79° 33-79° 34' E.
The setting to insert the grid is set to as following: [image] [image]

However the drawn co-ordinates is not matching with the co-ordinates of the region. I am using QGIS 3.16.0.

How can I correct the drawn co-ordinates in the map as to match it with the co-ordinates I mention above (extension of the area).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be wanting a grid in degrees-minutes-seconds but your stated interval is 1000.

Edit: Also, if you want to display a degree-minute-second grid then you have to set the Grid CRS to something that has units of degrees- like EGSG 4326. Then, when you change the grid interval to something like "0.05" you will get a grid spacing of about 3 minutes, which is probably close to what you want.

Comment: (Which means the interval is 1000 degrees)

Comment: Yes, @Leigh Battenay .It should be 30". I entered the interval of 30". But it didn't appear on the map. Therefore, I just entered the interval of 1000 to get something on the grid to post here that wrong co-ordinate appearance of the co-ordinates.

Comment: @Anand see edit made to answer. You can play around with the interval once you have it close.